# Likelihood ratio exponential family under permutation of parameters

Tags: likelihood-ratio, exponential-family, permutation

I'm reading "ASYMPTOTIC NORMALITY OF MAXIMUM LIKELIHOOD AND ITS VARIATIONAL APPROXIMATION FOR STOCHASTIC BLOCKMODELS" Bickel et al. 2013. In their proof of Lemma 3, they claim a result and I can't find a justification for it.

$f(A,Z;\theta)$ is the density function of an exponential family member. We assume that $(A,Z)$ are generated under $\theta_0$. Taking a non-identity permutation $\sigma$, they state that "by exponential family theory... it holds that $f(A,Z;\sigma(\theta))/f(A,Z;\sigma(\theta_0)) = o_P(1)$."

Does anyone have any understanding of why this true, or references where I might look to find an answer?